# Can I improve jQuery performance by combining all events of same type into one handler?

Tags: javascript, performance, event-handling, delegation, event-bubbling

I have a jQueryMobile site/app where performance is an issue. I am reading a lot about how it's smart not to bind too many separate handlers. So if you have a page with a lot of buttons , the advice is to bind like this...

```
$(document).on('click',function(){
   if (this = $('#button1')){
       //Handler for button one
   } else if (this = $('#button2') {
       //etc
   } else //etc
})
```

...rather than like this...

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
    //Handler for button one
})
$('#button2').click(function(){
    //Handler for button two
})
//etc
```

So I am wondering to what extent this is truly useful.

What if I made one listener for all 'pageshow' events in my document? (a jQueryMobile website is a single document containing many pages, and many of those pages need a bit of dolling up around showtime).

What if I made one click listener for all forty-odd buttons in the document, and used the handler to distinguish which button we're dealing with and what needs to be done in response?

Comment: Why not run some tests on jsperf?

Comment: "jQueryMobile ...performance is an issue" jQueryMobile is a bloated piece of crap that slows your website down by an order of magnitude. Use the DOM directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first option is faster to install and initialize, but slower to run when an event happens.

If you had hundreds of buttons with all nearly identical event handling, it might make sense to only install one event handler for all of them rather than run the code to install hundreds of event handlers.  But, you would still pay a small performance penalty when a particular event happens.

If you want to maximally optimize for run-time performance at the time of an event, it is still faster to install an event handler on the specific object you want to monitor.  That's because the event handlers are kept in a separate list just for that object and the code doesn't have to sort through a long list of event handlers to find which one is appropriate for that specific object and event.

Also, your if statement in the first option will never work for several reasons.  It would need to be something like this:

```
$(document).on('click',function(e) {
   if (e.target.id == 'button1') {
       //Handler for button one
   } else if (e.target.id == 'button2') {
       //etc
   } 
})
```

And, anytime you use delegated event handling, it's better to pick a common parent for the buttons that is much closer to the actual objects than the `document` object (helps runtime performance).

```
$("#buttonContainer").on('click',function(e) {
   if (e.target.id == 'button1') {
       //Handler for button one
   } else if (e.target.id == 'button2') {
       //etc
   } 
})
```

If you wanted just button clicks with delegated event handling, you could use some of the delgation features built into `.on()` like this

```
$("#buttonContainer").on('click', 'button', function(e) {
   if (this.id == 'button1') {
       //Handler for button one
   } else if (this.id == 'button2') {
       //etc
   } 
})
```

Comment: Hi jFriend, thanks for your answer (Yes, my first example is not going to work). I realize that I didn't quite get the essence of the .on() function and its possibility for delegating.
Are you saying with your answer that it is better to bind each button click directly with $('#buttonX').on('click', function(){}) than to bind each button click with delegation as in $('body').on('click','#buttonX',function(){}) ?

Comment: @Wytze - Please reread paragraphs two and three in my answer.  "Better" depends upon the layout of your page and what you're trying to optimize for.  I explained the tradeoffs in the first few paragraphs.

Comment: Hi jFriend, sorry about not picking that up. I want to optimize the general responsiveness to clicks and taps on buttons and links. On the one hand it would seem that I should minimize the number of active listeners (of all kinds, since any listener takes its toll in performance). On the other hand it might be that minimizing the number of listeners (through delegation) causes more delay, in waiting for the event to bubble up to the closest shared parent.

Comment: @Wytze - There is no need to minimize the total number of listeners.  If you have a 1000 objects each with it's own listener, that will give you good performance as events happen.  It will take more time to install the 1000 listeners initially, but once installed, they will perform well because there's only one listener on the object receiving the specific event.  Delegation does introduce some delay in the processing of the event.  Since events are usually user triggered and this delay is usually small, it is often not of consequence as long as the delegation is implemented appropriately.

Comment: @Wytze - As you can see there is no answer that is right in all cases.  Both work well, each with a few advantages and a few disadvantages.  As a programmer, you simply have to choose the tool that works better for your specific circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

The advice is, to use `event delegation`. You don't actually need to bind that "master event handler" to the `document` or `document.body`, you can (**and should**) bind it to the closest possible node that all buttons share.

```
$('#ClosestSharedParent').on('click', 'button', function( event ) {
    // "this" references the button that was actually clicked
    switch( event.id ) {
        case 'button1':
            alert('button1 clicked');
            break;
        case 'button2':
            alert('button2 clicked');
            break;
        // and so on
    }
});
```

The second argument from `.on()` accepts a selector, where you can specify which elements you want to delegate events for. In older version of jQuery, this was accomplished by the `.delegate()` method.

Ref.: [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: Thanks jAndy! In my jQueryMobile situation, one type of event can occur on elements in many different "pages" and all those pages' first shared parent is body, so I'll stick to body in this case.

Comment: You don't need to bind (nor should) it to the closet possible node. Just bind it to `document` and use the capture phase. Besides why does binding it to the closest parent help, at all?

Comment: @Raynos: because you are able to prevent events from further propagation.

Comment: @jAndy only if you call `stopPropagation` and you really shouldn't do that because it kills the ability to do event delegation. Next time you do `delegate(document, condition, handler)` and then wonder why it doesnt work then see some noob call `ev.stopPropagation` you will ragequit

Comment: @Raynos: no clue what you're talking about nor why you're saying "you shouldn't do that" just like that, but preventing events from further propagation can be a very useful thing.

Comment: if you stop an event from further propagation then any other delegated event handler higher up the chain can't catch that event because you killed it. It makes your code highly inflexible, it's the same as calling `Object.freeze` on everything and then ragequitting later about how you can't extend objects.

Comment: You can stop teaching me, I know all this stuff, doing the job long enough. There are situations where you exactly want this bevahior anyway. I totally don't like things like "don't do that" without thinking it through entirely.

Comment: Well guys, all I can say in your discussion is that I think stopping event propagation is not a problem in my situation. I listen for button clicks and pageBeforeShow events, and whenever these events happen I don't see any realistic possibility for wanting the event to bubble up any further. Do I understand correctly that I will have to manually specify e.stopPropagation in each handler?